# Replace a SherlockFragment with another one

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I'm using ActionBarSherlock library, and I want to replace current SherlockFragment with another one, i tried to compile that but it says that the target class is not a Fragment(But it extends SherlockFragment):

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.replace(R.id.details, new Student(), "Student"); 
ft.commit();
```

How can I make that with SherlockFragment.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Is Student declared with `public class Student extends SherlockFragment {`? Please post the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()` is undefined for the class that I want to replace it with the other sherlockfragment. It extends SherlockFragment too.

Comment: You have to be in a `SherlockFragmentActivity`

Comment: I have a ClassCastException. MainFragment can not be cast to android.app.activity. Any help please?

Comment: Fragments aren't Activitites. You have to do this in the activity or at least get the support fragment manager from the activity. You can get the activity by calling `getSherlockActivity()` though.

Comment: I'm doing this in a `SherlockFragmentActivity` as you mentionned. So `SherlockFragmentActivity` starts a `SherlockFragment`. Can you please give more details/edit code? Fragments/Sherlock lib is a whole new concept for me.

Comment: You have to show some  more code I'm afraid, not sure where your class cast exception is coming from, sounds like you are trying to cast your fragment to an activity which wont' work of course. Sherlock Fragments are just like ordinary Fragments just have to use the SupportFragmentManager instead. Look for some examples elsewhere.

Comment: Just another question please: what container should I put in .replace arguments? The MainFragment one or target(Etudiant) one? Container can be Relative/Linear/Frame/Table layouts? Am I correct?

Comment: The fragment container. For further information please see the Fragement guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I was doing a very big mistake. I would like to start a SherlockFragmentActivity not a SherlockFragment. That's why I had a classcastexception. However, do you know how to start a `SherlockFragmentActivity ` from a `SherlockFragmentActivity` ? I'm having now a problem in the .replace. Just that problem now.

Comment: At least tell me please if that is possible or not.

Comment: Just with normal Intent. Thank you for answering in my previous questions ;).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
getSupportFragmentManager();
```